# How can i make this code work properly, its based on a for-loop and is not completing its process

Tags: javascript, for-loop, str-replace

```
for (let i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
  ans = ans.replace(' ', '+');
  ans = ans.replace('  ', '+');
  ans = ans.replace('++', '+');
  //here ans is a value of an input.
}
```

Why is this stopping before completing the process?

Comment: Could you describe what your goal is and what the issue is in more detail?

Comment: Well, when an input is entered, a function is called, in that function to replace all spaces with '+', i had added this for loop

Comment: but its output comes like 'what+is         example'

Comment: What exactly does "not completing it's process" mean? Provide some sample input and expected results as per [mre] along with an explanation of what the code is doing differently than you expect

Comment: It just stops replacing ' ' with +

Comment: And tells that the loop is finished

Answer (score 1):

You are performing the same action in each iteration of the loop, so the loop is redundant in this code block. If you meant to replace all occurrences, a regex replacement is better:

```
ans = ans.replace(/ /g, '+');
ans = ans.replace(/  /g, '+');
ans = ans.replace(/\+\+/g, '+');
```

If you are only targeting modern browsers, you can use `replaceAll` instead:

```
ans = ans.replaceAll(' ', '+');
ans = ans.replaceAll('  ', '+');
ans = ans.replaceAll('++', '+');
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks a lot @Wais Kamal

Answer (score 1):

Well based on the code I see you want to get rid of spaces no matter how many in a row, So I suggest [**Regular Expression**](https://regexone.com) :

```js
let ans = "im an input here   so you can see the stuff"
ans = ans.replace(/\s+/g , '+'); \* im+an+input+here+so+you+can+see+the+stuff *\
```

How ever as it's been said on [Wais Kamal Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70260436/10036042) you can use `replaceAll()` as well for different cases

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this stopping before completing the process?

To answer your only question, the loop ends prematurely because you write to `ans` variable and therefore you change the length of `ans` variable (that is used as condition in the `for` loop). So if you shorten its length, the loop stops earlier (as the new length is not reflected).

But check others answers on how to write it better.